# URL changes while using proxy and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am new to web scraping so please forgive my ignorance.

I built a program to scrape Zillow, and everything has worked fine for the most part. My problem is I am using a proxy service called proxycrawl that easily allows me to integrate proxies into my program. This is done by placing https://api.proxycrawl.com/?token=xxx&url= before my actual URL. What I have noticed is that when the program clicks on an "a" tag, the URL changes to the example below:

Before:
[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F5Tq.png)

After:
[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jAK8.png)

Any 11 clicks through the program or manually result in the site changing to the proxycrawl site, where I get the 404 error. Any ideas?

```
#Browser open
print(".....Opening Browser.....")
Browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
Browser.maximize_window()

#browser page
url = urllib.parse.quote_plus('https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Bakersfield-CA-93312/house,mobile,land,townhouse_type/97227_rid/35.4606,-119.037467,35.317856,-119.200888_rect/12_zm/0_mmm/')
Browser.get('https://api.proxycrawl.com/?token=xxx&url=' + url)
print("Opening Zillow")
time.sleep(10)

last_page = int(Browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//ol[@class="zsg-pagination"]//li[last()-1]""").text)
#print last_page
page = 0
count = 0

csv_file = open('listings.csv','w')

fieldnames = ['address', 'price', 'zestimate', 'beds', 'baths', 'feet', 'desc', 'Type', 'year_built', 'heating', 'cooling', 'parking', 'lot',
               'days_on_market', 'pricepsqr', 'saves', 'interior', 'spaces_amenities', 'construction', 'exterior', 'parking1', 'mls', 'other']

writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
for i in range(last_page):
    page = page + 1
    n = 0
    listings = Browser.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="search-results"]/ul/li""")

    for i in range(len(listings)):
        n = i + 1

        listing_dict = {}

        print("Scraping the listing number {0} on page {1}, the count is {2}".format(n, page, count))
        if (count) % 11 == 0:
            listings = Browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/ul/li')
            time.sleep(2)

            try:
                # Finds Listings
                 listings = Browser.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="search-results"]/ul/li""")
                 print("Looking Up listings")

                 # Opens Listing
                 listings[i].find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0].click()
                 print("Opening Listing")
                 time.sleep(2)

                 # Opens "See More Tab"
                 Browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('See More').click()

                 # Prepare for Scrape
                 time.sleep(2)
```

I did speak with proxycrawl, and they stated that the URL had to be encoded, which I did do with no luck. After encoding, I replied and got the following statement:

"You are sending your requests double encoded and your get a response of pc_status: 602. Those requests are failing and you should fix them. Please only encode the URLs once, encoding the URLs more than once will result in a failing request."

Answer (score 0):

It look like the page is trying to redirect you relatively.

In this specific use case, you could hack your way around the encoding issue by doing something similar to the following

```
# https://api.proxycrawl.com/homes/for_sale/Test/one,two
x = driver.current_url

#/homes/for_sale/Test/one,two
r = x[26:]

# base url = https://api.proxycrawl.com/?token=xxx&url=
u = base_url + r

driver.get(u)
```

Comment: Will try this tonight!